# Color of table cells

Tags: cellcolor

I am having trouble coloring table cells. In the MWE below the color leaves white space at the right. Thinking that this may be due to internal length calculations I explicitly set the lenghts of multicolumns, taking into account tabcolsep values but the problem persists

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\tiny\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.200cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} { | C{4.500cm} |  C{4.334cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} |}\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|p{14.65cm}|}{\centering\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{\bfseries\footnotesize REQUIREMENTS}}\\\hline
%
\cellcolor{blue}&
\cellcolor{blue}&
\multicolumn{4}{p{5.016cm}|}{\centering\tiny\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{EDUCATION}} \\\cline{2-6}
%
\multicolumn{1}{|p{4.500cm}|}{\centering\multirow{-2}{*}{\tiny\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{AREA}}}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{4.334cm}|}{\centering\multirow{-2}{*}{\tiny\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{PROFILE}}}&
\centering\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{U}&
 \centering\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{P}& 
 \centering\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{I}& 
 \centering\arraybackslash\cellcolor{blue}\textcolor{yellow}{M} \\
%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to take into account the column separating spaces. The problem is solved with replacing the multicolumn specifier to `c` since you want a centred contents. I simplified your code, , systematically using the `\rowcolor` command, changed the colour to have more visible lines and used `\hhline` in the place of `\cline`. This being said, I'm unsure of the final result you're aiming at.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\tiny\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.200cm}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{blue} {cyan!40}

\begin{tabular} { | C{4.500cm} | C{4.334cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} | C{0.954cm} |}\hline
\rowcolor{blue}\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textcolor{yellow}{\bfseries\footnotesize REQUIREMENTS}}\\\hline
% %p{14.65cm}
\rowcolor{blue}& &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\tiny\textcolor{yellow}{EDUCATION}} \\\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-----|}
\rowcolor{blue}%
\multirow{-2}{=}{\centering\tiny\textcolor{yellow}{AREA}}&
\multirow{-2}{=}{\centering\tiny\textcolor{yellow}{PROFILE}}&
\centering\textcolor{yellow}{U}&
 \centering\textcolor{yellow}{P}&
 \centering\textcolor{yellow}{I}&
 \centering\arraybackslash\textcolor{yellow}{M} \\%
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernard, I have had this problem for a long time and tried several options. I think that I had taken into account the colsep, my calculation for the first multicolumn was 12.65 cm plus 0.2cm x 10 = 14.65 cm, this plus the two separations (0.2 cm x 2) of the single multicolumn gives 15.05 cm which is the width of the table